# CKeditor adds new paragraph with new line character

Tags: ckeditor

Well as explained in title, I have a problem with CKeditor.

For example i have textarea with text `<p>sample text</p>`. I change this text in CKeditor so it says `<p>sample text changed</p>`, and press a `Save` button. Data gets inserted into database but like this: `<p>sample text changed</p><p>\n</p>`.

Basically it adds another paragraph with new line character in it.
Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can choose an another "enterMode" :

```
enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P,
```